# mat-slide-toggle : maintain color depth even disabled

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

The `mat-slide-toggle` color will be paled when `[disabled]=true` as in the [example site](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/examples), but I want the color depth to be maintained even `[disabled]=true`.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override Material style in your CSS turning off opacity like this :

```
.mat-slide-toggle.mat-disabled {
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the direct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I end up setting `(click)="$event.preventDefault();"` instead of `[disabled]="true"`.